# Azure Data Factory - Upset then Delete

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a process that dumps json files into Azure Storage Blobs. I'm using an Azure Data Factory to Upsert the blobs to a Azure CosmosDB.

Once the json is upserted to CosmosDB I want it removed from storage.

I can add a Delete action to the workflow, but that risks deleting a json file that has not yet been processed.

Is it possible to set the Data Factory to 'Delete after Upsert' or simlar?
Any other suggestions?

EDIT: Adding image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** Create Pipeline

**Step2:** Select Dataflow activity

**Step3:** Here you will see Delete Source files after completion option. As shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the ADF activity, you'll see this option on your Source transformation:

[image]

Comment: thanks @Mark, I added a screenshot to the original post. The funny thing is when I first tested this, I thought I saw the option you highlighted -- but I do not see it now. Any ideas? Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You'll only see that option for storage sources, so maybe you selected a different source type?